Applying styles to different columns in table
I am getting an error when trying to apply a color to specific columns when creating a table with reportlab.
Here is my entire script for a reproducible example (you will need to put an output path on line 109):
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from reportlab.platypus import Frame
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import PageTemplate
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import Table, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import NextPageTemplate, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle

def on_page(canvas, doc, pagesize=A4):
    page_num = canvas.getPageNumber()
    canvas.drawCentredString(pagesize[0]/2, 50, str(page_num))

    now = datetime.now()
    today = now.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  
    current_time = now.strftime("%I:%M %p") 

    canvas.drawString(50, pagesize[1] - 50, f"{today}")
    canvas.drawString(50, pagesize[1] - 70, f"{current_time}") 

def on_page_landscape(canvas, doc):

  return on_page(canvas, doc, pagesize=landscape(A4))

def format_nums(num):
    if num < 0: 
       x = '(${:.2f})'.format(abs(num))
    elif num > 0:
        x = '${:.2f}'.format(num)
    else:
       x = '${:.0f}'.format(num)

    return x

def df2table(df, custom_style):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'float64':
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: format_nums(x)) 

    #('BACKGROUND', (start_col, start_row), (end_col, end_row), color)
    return Table(
        [[Paragraph(col, custom_style) for col in df.columns]] + df.values.tolist(),
        style = [
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),  # Header font
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8),  # Body font size
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),  # Header text color
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightgrey),  # Header background color
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (0, 0), colors.lightblue),  # first Header background color
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (0, -1), colors.lightblue),  # First column background color
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),  # Line below header
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),  # Inner grid lines
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black)],  # Outer box
        hAlign = 'LEFT')

def df2table2(df, custom_style, commodity_cols):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == 'float64':
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: format_nums(x))

    data = [[Paragraph(col, custom_style) for col in df.columns]] + df.values.tolist()
    
    #('BACKGROUND', (start_col, start_row), (end_col, end_row), color)
    style = [
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),  # Header font
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8),  # Body font size
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),  # Header text color
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightgrey),  # Header background color
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),  # Line below header
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),  # Inner grid lines
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black)]  # Outer box
    
    # Apply colors based on column types
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns): 
        if col in commodity_cols:
            style.append(('BACKGROUND', (i, 1), (i, -1), colors.lightgrey))  # Commodity column
        else:
            if col != 'Counterparty':
                style.append(('BACKGROUND', (i, 1), (i, -1), colors.lightgreen))  # Aggregation column

    return Table(data, style, hAlign='LEFT')

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Counterparty': ['foo', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz','fizz', 'foo'],
        'Commodity': ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','bar', 'ab cred'],
        'DealType': ['Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy'],
        'StartDate': ['07/01/2024', '09/01/2024', '10/01/2024', '11/01/2024', '12/01/2024', '01/01/2025'],
        'FloatPrice': [18.73, 17.12, 17.76, 18.72, 19.47, 20.26],
        'MTMValue':[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
        })

commodity_cols = df['Commodity'].unique()

out = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'MTMValue', index='Counterparty', columns = 'Commodity', aggfunc='sum').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).fillna(0)
out['Cumulative Exposure'] = out[out.columns[1:]].sum(axis = 1)

path = <INSERT PDF OUTPUT FILE HERE>

padding = dict(
    leftPadding=72, 
    rightPadding=72,
    topPadding=72,
    bottomPadding=18)

portrait_frame = Frame(0, 0, *A4, **padding)
landscape_frame = Frame(0, 0, *landscape(A4), **padding)
            
portrait_template = PageTemplate(
    id='portrait', 
    frames=portrait_frame,
    onPage=on_page, 
    pagesize=A4)

landscape_template = PageTemplate(
    id='landscape', 
    frames=landscape_frame, 
    onPage=on_page_landscape, 
    pagesize=landscape(A4))

doc = BaseDocTemplate(
    path,
    pageTemplates=[
    #portrait_template
    landscape_template
    ]
)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
custom_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CustomStyle', fontSize=8)

# NOT WOKRING
#story = [
#    Paragraph('Title 1', styles['Title']),
#    Paragraph('Title 2', styles['Title']),
#    Paragraph("<br/><br/>", styles['Normal']),
#    Paragraph('Current Total Positions', styles['Heading2']),
#    df2table2(out, custom_style, commodity_cols)
#]

# WORKING
story = [
    Paragraph('Title 1', styles['Title']),
    Paragraph('Tilte 2', styles['Title']),
    Paragraph("<br/><br/>", styles['Normal']),
    Paragraph('Current Total Positions', styles['Heading2']),
    df2table(out, custom_style)
]

doc.build(story)

My issue arises in the df2table2 function somewhere with the full error message:
unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'float' and 'tuple'

I have been looking at this for hours and cannot for the life of me figure out what is possibly going wrong. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Hi, I am unable to reproduce this. Just tried this code, and it is running just fine. Also, how is this the full error message? Where is the full traceback? Anyway, the message mentions the use of -=, and the code shared does not include this operator. E.g., you could reproduce this error by doing fl = 1.0; fl -= 0,5 (notice the comma), where someone probably meant to do: fl = 1.0; fl -= 0.5. Something like that, but as said: your code doesn't include that operator...

@ouroboros1 there are two blocks of code at the bottom. One of them uses the df2table function which works. The other uses the df2table2 function which gives the error. In regard to the full traceback, That is all that is given to me when I run the code. I don't perform any operation -= which is why I am so confused as to why This is the error I am getting

@ouroboros1 Another thing I tried to debug was taking style list that is produced from df2table2 and pasting the output into df2table and editing the colors back to the format color.white or whatever and running that and it works fine. But running the df2table2 function results in error

You wrote: "In regard to the full traceback, That is all that is given to me when I run the code". In what kind of environment are you running this code? Normally, you'd expect a more detailed error message, which is crucial for effective debugging. If you're not seeing the full traceback, it might be worth exploring an alternative environment or adjusting settings to get more insights.

@ouroboros1 I am using visual studio and just using a default python environment with some extra libraries installed

The problem lies with your return statement:
def df2table2(df, custom_style, commodity_cols):

    # ...

    data = [[Paragraph(col, custom_style) for col in df.columns]] + df.values.tolist()
    
    #('BACKGROUND', (start_col, start_row), (end_col, end_row), color)
    style = [
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),  # Header font
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8),  # Body font size
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),  # Header text color
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightgrey),  # Header background color
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),  # Line below header
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),  # Inner grid lines
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black)]  # Outer box
    
    # ...

    return Table(data, style, hAlign='LEFT')

Note that you are using style as a positional argument. Here's part of the signature of Table:
Table(
    data,
    colWidths=None,
    rowHeights=None,
    style=None,
    ...
    )

Meaning: here style is the fourth parameter, but when you pass style as a positional argument, it gets passed to the second parameter, i.e., colWidths, which apparently expects floats, rather than tuples, such as ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'), etc.
So, the fix is to use keyword arguments:
def df2table2(df, custom_style, commodity_cols):

    # ...

    return Table(data=data, style=style, hAlign='LEFT')

Or, if you want to use positional arguments, to add values for colWidths and rowHeights before adding style:
    return Table(data, None, None, style, hAlign='LEFT')

Snippet from result after fix:


bless you! That works
